# Trying to parse characters with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex on an exchange server to match the rule "does the email address have a number in character 1,2 or 3"

I've never used RegEx before, but i came up with the following, which ALMOST works!

^([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]).*@domain.com

It works if Char 2 or 3 are numbers, but not the first character

Can someone see / explain where i am going wrong?

Many thanks,

J

Comment: Thanks for that, and thanks for explaining and not just showing, it really helps to understand. One thing i don't understand is that that rule checks out in the tool you linked to, but not in gskinner.com/RegExr/ which is the tool i've been using.

Comment: You can test it on your site with the option "multiline" : [here](http://regexr.com?342uk)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is cheking if the first character is a digit (`[0-9]`), a digit(`[0-9]`) or a digit(`[0-9]`) : `([0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])`

You can do what you want whith this :

```
^([0-9]..|.[0-9].|..[0-9]).*@domain.com
```

This check if your string start with :

`[0-9]..` a digit followed by two characters

`.[0-9].` a character, a digit and one more character

`..[0-9]` two characters and a digit

You can test it [here](http://rubular.com/r/eRiGdkntwB)

Answer (score 1):

You are going wrong by using [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in your brackets when you are really trying to match characters at positions.

If you want to match numbers at position 1, 2 OR 3, this would work:

```
^[0-9]|^.[0-9]|^..[0-9]
```

Note that this is not going to validate your string as an email address, but assuming you feed only valid email addresses to the regex it will match what you want it to match.